Left join with hierarchical table produces duplicate rows
This question is building on previous one I asked here
I have the following tables based on the answer in the mentioned post (simplified):

This works perfectly when I want to query wallet_balance_history along with the first level parent category category_id references the top-level parent in categories table. What I am struggling with is, If I want to query lower level categories, I get duplicated rows for the same wallet_balance_history row, because the category_id in that particular row has more than one child category_id.
Here is a simplified example - table Wallet_balance_history:



ID
category_id




1
4


2
4



Table categories:



ID
parent_id
name




4
null
x1


5
4
x1.1


6
4
x1.2



When I run the following query:
select 
    wbh.id id, c1.name c1, c2.name c2, c3.name c3
from
    wallets_balance_history wbh 
left join 
    categories c1 on wbh.category_id = c1.id
left join 
    categories c2 on c2.parent_id = c1.id
left join 
    categories c3 on c3.parent_id = c2.id
where 
    wbh.id = 1;

I will get the following result set:



ID
c1
c2




1
x1
x1.1


1
x1
x1.2



What I want to achieve is for every wallet_balance_history row (unique on ID), there should be at max one c1, one 2, one 3. So when I query the transactions I get something like this:



ID
c1
c2




1
x1
x1.1



I know with the current design, I can't achieve this. I understand there is no way for the query to know the category_id for the child.
I thought of two options:

In wallets_balance_history.category_id should have the lowest child (from child, I can find the parent category, but not necessarily the other way around if I have multiple children). The problem with this, is I won't know what category level is there. It's the lowest, but it could third, second of first, and it could create other complexities.
Resort to creating a bridging table where for each wallet_balance_history.id, is mapped to one or more rows depending on how many categories/child categories in that transaction.


What are you expecting? As there are 2 distinct c2 values so that = 2 rows. If that isn't what you want show us what is you do want.

@PaulMaxwell, I added more details. I need to change my tables design, don't I?

Use a LATERAL join to a hierarchical query and then pivot the rows to columns:
SELECT wbh.id,
       c.c1, 
       c.c2,
       c.c3
FROM   wallet_balance_history wbh
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT MIN(CASE LEVEL WHEN 1 THEN name END) AS c1,
                MIN(CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN name END) AS c2,
                MIN(CASE LEVEL WHEN 3 THEN name END) AS c3
         FROM   categories c
         WHERE  LEVEL <= 3
         START WITH c.id = wbh.category_id
         CONNECT BY PRIOR c.id = c.parent_id
       ) c
       ON (1 = 1)
WHERE  wbh.id = 1;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Wallet_balance_history (ID, category_id) AS
SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE categories(ID, parent_id, name) AS
SELECT 4, null, 'x1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4,    'x1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 4,    'x1.2' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
C1
C2
C3




1
x1
x1.1
null



fiddle

@MTO, Thanks. I am new to lateral join. My question is why in the output it returned C2=x1.1 insead of C2=x1.2? Both outputs are children of x1

@Hawk It returns x1.1 because that is the minimum value of x1.1 and x1.2 and the query uses MIN. As for why, because that is the output you expected in the question.

With the data structure as provided in the question all you need is one selfjoin and simple aggregations grouped by category_id:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table wallet_balance_history (ID Number(6), CATEGORY_ID Number(6));

Insert Into Wallet_balance_history 
Select 1, 4 From Dual Union All
Select 2, 4 From Dual Union All
Select 3, 7 From Dual;
 
Select * From wallet_balance_history;




ID
CATEGORY_ID




1
4


2
4


3
7



--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table categories (ID Number(6), PARENT_ID Number(6), NAME Varchar2(32));

Insert Into categories
Select 4, Null, 'x1'   From Dual Union All
Select 5,    4, 'x1.1' From Dual Union All
Select 6,    4, 'x1.2' From Dual Union All 
Select 7, Null, 'y1'   From Dual Union All
Select 8,    7, 'y1.1' From Dual Union All
Select 9,    7, 'y1.2' From Dual;

Select * From categories;




ID
PARENT_ID
NAME




4
null
x1


5
4
x1.1


6
4
x1.2


7
null
y1


8
7
y1.1


9
7
y1.2



--      S Q L :  
Select    Min(w.id) as id, 
          Max(c_0.name) as c1,  
          Min(c_1.name) as c2, 
          Max(c_1.name) as c3
From      wallet_balance_history w
Left Join categories c_0 ON( c_0.id = w.category_id )
Left Join categories c_1 ON( c_1.parent_id = c_0.id )
Group By  w.category_id

R e s u l t :



ID
C1
C2
C3




1
x1
x1.1
x1.2


3
y1
y1.1
y1.2



fiddle
